Why circle signifying brush in sculp mode isn’t round?
I can’t do round circle-shape touch in sculpt mode, my stretch brush draws stripes. 



Because you have scaled your object in Object Mode (in Z direction as it seems) and did not apply the scale with Ctrl+A > Apply > Scale.

Thanks a lot! :)
